# Siri programming language

Tags: iphone, artificial-intelligence, siri, sirikit

Supposedly, the engine behind the iPhone's new Siri feature has been under development for several years (spawned from the CALO project). It is said that they even developed a new programming language specifically for it.

I can't find information about it anywhere. The only possible leads are academic papers, but I am not in an university network, so I don't have access to most of them.

Does anyone have any leads, examples, or even something vague as "it is similar to Prolog" or perhaps "it is a dialect of Lisp"?

Comment: "In the first four years of the project, CALO-funded research has resulted in more than five hundred publications across all fields of artificial intelligence."- I'd say that qualifies it as an AI project.

Comment: I wonder if some or all was ported to Objective-C...

Comment: I haven't seen anything about a Siri programming language in [Tom Gruber's publications](http://tomgruber.org/writing.htm) (he is the founder of Siri and product lead at Apple).

Comment: More important than the language is the way the data is organized and how is pulled from Siri. Any language wouldn't make a big difference as long they have the same algorithm/APIs. Am I wrong?

Comment: @nacho4d No, you are correct, up to a point. It has to deal with the level of abstraction. If the majority of Siri was coded in say, C, but they had devised a nice DSL to express some of their algorithms or data structures, that would be very interesting in itself. In fact, I'd be surprised if they didn't do something like that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In terms of the Siri work, the direct predecessor ( http://www.sri.com/about/siri-timeline.html), the Personalized Assistant that Learns (PAL) Program, did produce an "agent-based language/framework" SPARK (not to be confused with SPARK Ada). They have publicly available documentation on it http://www.ai.sri.com/~spark/, https://pal.sri.com/CALOfiles/cstore/PAL-publications/calo/2005/IntrotoSPARK.pdf, and http://www.ai.sri.com/pubs/files/1023.pdf (and an Eclipse plugin, apparently). This is very different from a general-purpose programming language. The "language" is more of a language in the sense that it models a specific formalism for planning and knowledge representation (think semantic web rather than programming language). The framework itself is hosted in Python and sometimes Java.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't for the life of me remember where I had seen it. I had the impression that it was a general-purpose programming language, but a planning or knowledge representation language sounds even better. I am specially interested in agents lately, and I'm reading all papers I can find about NASA's Remote Agent Experiment (which flew on DS-1).

Answer (score 4):

From [this blog post](http://scobleizer.com/2010/02/08/why-if-you-miss-siri-youll-miss-the-future-of-the-web/):

> Siri has developed a new programming language and GUI for the API web.
>   This is huge, although it’s too bad that it’s so early and so hidden.

There is a video in that blog post that shows the owner of the website interviewing two important figures from Siri, and they discuss what you asked about and much more.